# How do exit a while loop with a JOptionPane

Tags: java

I am having trouble with my code, I am trying to exit this loop if the user clicks on the `CANCEL.OPTION` or the `CLOSED.OPTION`. I handled the exception but can't seem to be able to use the buttons on the window. The program gets the users birthyear from their input of their age. The problem i am having is that I cannot end the loop through the buttons. Thanks in advance!

```
public Integer getBirthYear() {
    boolean prompt = true;
    while(prompt) {
        String enteredAge = showInputDialog(null,"Enter age:");
        try {
            age = Integer.parseInt(enteredAge);
            if(age == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION || age == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) {
                System.out.println("MADE IT INTO IF");
            }
            age = year - age;
            prompt = false;
            showMessageDialog(null,age);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return age;
}
```

Comment: put your promp = false outside of try and catch clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several overloaded versions of showInputDialog, with different parameters. Only the javadoc of the last version documents correctly that the return value is null when the user pressed cancel.

```
public int getBirthYear() {
    boolean prompt = true;
    while (prompt) {
        String enteredAge = showInputDialog(null,"Enter age:");
        if (enteredAge == null) { // Cancel pressed
            age = -1;
            prompt = false;
        } else {
            try {
                age = Integer.parseInt(enteredAge);
                age = year - age;
                prompt = false;
                showMessageDialog(null, age);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                showMessageDialog(null, "Enter a valid number");
            }
        }
    }
    return age;
}
```

It might be you want to restructure the program a bit; make age a local variable or whatever. Use `int` for real integer values. `Integer` is the Object wrapper class for an int.

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest answer to your question is, just put promp = false outside of your try and catch clause and it should work:

```
public Integer getBirthYear() {
boolean prompt = true;
while(prompt) {
    String enteredAge = showInputDialog(null,"Enter age:");
    try {
        age = Integer.parseInt(enteredAge);
        if(age == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION || age == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("MADE IT INTO IF");
        }
        age = year - age;
        showMessageDialog(null,age);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        prompt = false;
}
return age;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the scope. The entered age wasnt making it into the catch block. I resolved that issue.

```
    public Integer getBirthYear() {
    boolean prompt = true;
    do {
        try {
            age = year - Integer.parseInt(showInputDialog(null,"Enter age:"));
            prompt = false;
            showMessageDialog(null, age);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            String ageEntered = showInputDialog(null,"Enter age:");
            e.printStackTrace();
            if(ageEntered == null) { //close the file if Cancel is chosen
                prompt = false;
            }
        }
    } while(prompt);
    return age;
}
```